# Vertex Cosine Similarity of a weighted graph

Tags: graph-theory, wolfram-alpha, spectral-graph-theory

I'm trying to calculate the vertex cosine similarity of a weighted directional graph, however struggling to understand the concept. While I understand the methodology for simple and directed graphs, weighted has me stumped.  I'm following the examples provided by wolfram [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexCosineSimilarity.html) however with the weighted example I cannot work out how they get to a value of 0.395103.  They describe the calculation as:

```
(number of shared nodes)/sqrt(number of edges on node 1 * number of edges on node 2)
```

however do not explain where edges weight comes into play.  My assumption would be that the calculation should be the following:

```
1/sqrt((1.4+1.6) * (1.2+1.6)) = 0.345033
```

Can't see how else you would involve graph weight but obviously this is an incorrect result.  Any clues would be appreciated.

Comment: As it says [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_%28network_science%29#Cosine_similarity), what you do is find the cosine of the angle between the two row vectors of the adjacency matrix corresponding to the vertices under consideration. In the case of a weighted graph, the adjacency matrix will have entries other than $0$ and $1$.

Comment: can you please provide a worked example?

Comment: Done, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A graph having edges with real weights has an adjacency matrix $W$ with real entries. The example graph given in the [Wolfram page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexCosineSimilarity.html) has the adjacency matrix shown below.

\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1.6 & 1.4 & 0\\
1.6 & 0 & 1.2 & 0\\
1.4 & 1.2 & 0 & 2.5\\
0 & 0 & 2.5 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

The [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_%28network_science%29#Cosine_similarity/) between vertices $v_i$ and $v_j$ is the cosine of the angle between the $i$-th and $j$-th rows of the adjacency matrix $W$, regarded as vectors. That is (letting $W^i$ and $W^j$ denote the $i$-th and $j$-th rows of $W$ respectively),
\begin{equation*}
\sigma_{ij} = \dfrac{W^i \cdot W^j}{\|W^i\| \|W^j\|}
= \dfrac{\sum\limits_k w_{ik}w_{jk}}{\sqrt{\left(\sum\limits_k w_{ik}^2\right) \left(\sum\limits_k w_{jk}^2\right)}}
\end{equation*}

This is just the sum of the products of weights $w_{ik}$ and $w_{jk}$ for each common neighbor $v_k$ of $v_i$ and $v_j$, divided by the geometric mean of the sum of squares of weights of edges incident with each of the vertices $v_i$ and $v_j$.

For vertices $1$ and $2$ in the example graph, this is
\begin{equation*}
\sigma_{12} = \dfrac{1.2 \times 1.4}{\sqrt{(1.6^2 + 1.4^2)(1.6^2 + 1.2^2)}} \approxeq 0.395103.
\end{equation*}

Comment: Thanks Vinay, I had working it out just before you posted this so sorry for wasting your time but hopefully others will find this usefull.

Comment: @jhole89 Oh, no problem. Thanks for the accept!

Comment: @M.Vinay what about undirected graphs. How to compute their cosine similarity?

Comment: @Vineet In my understanding, the definition is the same for undirected and directed graphs – the example in the answer is actually an undirected graph, since the adjacency matrix is symmetric, although it might as well have been directed. Since the angle being computed is that between two rows, the weights of the outgoing edges will be considered. Now if you meant to ask about *unweighted* graphs… you can still use the usual $0$-$1$ adjacency matrix with the same definition of cosine similarity.