# Similarity of weighted graphs with shared Node

Tags: graph-theory

Related to question already posted in: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38305/similarity-of-weighted-graphs

My question further extends to graph with shared vertices (node) by using Gromov-Hausdorff distance to measure similarity. (Undirectional, Weighted)

Assume G1 with N1 connect to H1, H2, H3 with weight W1, W2, W3.

G2 with N2 connect to H2, H3, H4 with weight W4, W5, W6.

My understanding of GH distance is to covert the weights into metric spaces 
$X=\{W1,W2,W3\}$ and $Y=\{W4,W5,W6\}$
Now we now X and Y both connect to H2 and H3 with different weights, while we can treat H1 with 0 weight for Y and H4 with 0 weight for X.

My understanding of Hausdorff distance is a shape, but When we calculate $d_{DG}(X,Y)$ by d(W1,W4), d(W1,W5) how we can exactly do it? Or does it still apply ?

Further question is what is the best way to measure the similarity of N1 and N2 given u have a weighted graph as described. Will GH distance together with jaccard similarity of {H} set give better information ? 
One of the intuitively way I was think is to measure N1 N2 distance as a sum up all the edge difference square of all connected H node. What is the difference and which is better ?

I come across question [Vertex Cosine Similarity of a weighted graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1799509/vertex-cosine-similarity-of-a-weighted-graph). But this question is about directional graph. what is the difference?

Sorry if my question sounds naive, i am from computer science background and trying to solve so graph similarity problem.

Thank you !